# (Combine 3 columns into one in excel 2011 for mac) plus change formula into usable number

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

If I set up the following, from a previous Applemac - from a “Superuser“ - excel solution.
(Combine 3 columns into one in excel 2011 for mac)

I enter column D to use the formula =CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1) = it Works thus far. 
the prior instruction’s then say “Then delete columns ABC“ 
+++ If I then delete (columns ABC) the “Needed” (D Column) formula disappears in error’s.

---

Is it possible,
Then to change column D, or even Column E, into a firm useable numerical total. 
Ie = [01234567890] (11 Characters) in either - column‘s  D or E or Any Column.

---

**** My problem is part of several thousands of telephone customers+Suppliers+Friends phone  numbers, are now in 3 Column’s of Excel work books, which I need, for dialling purposes into  one Column Characters (2+3+6=11) Characters, in UK Phone Numbers.

---

In England - Column A is the UK- (01 (Work/Home nos)),
or (UK-07(Mobile Nos)) [ie we will use (01)]

Column B is (Three characters for an Area Type Code) [ie use (234)] 
Column C is the Actual Six Characters - personal Number [ie use(678901)
= (creating the Needed Total of (11 Eleven) Characters  ie Total - (01234567890)

---

Is it possible,  then to make column D, or any other Column say (E), into a firm useable  total, And then get rid of the Concatenated Columns (A,B,C,D).

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Ken Goodwin

Answer (score 0):

There is a really quick solution to this - copy the column you create, and use `Edit >> Paste Special` to paste the values into another column.  I'm sure there must be a way to create what you are asking for in one step, but this is how I have always done it when needed - it's nice and simple.

Once you have pasted the values, simply delete the other columns, including the formula based one and you should get no errors this time.